# Trying to remove XML tags based on attribute value using Jsoup java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jsoup

im trying to remove xml elements based on attribute value kind='lib. when i print out the file the content is removed but when i write to file and open the file i see extra elements are removed that are not given in the condition. i can see kind ='con' is removed but i would need to keep this

my code

```
Path classPath=Paths.get(prop.getProperty("testClasspath"));
        String pomFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(classPath),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         
         Document doc_classpath = Jsoup.parse(pomFile,"",Parser.xmlParser());


            //for pretty xml formating
            doc_classpath.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
          
   
            doc_classpath.select("[kind=lib]").remove();
            System.out.println(doc_classpath.toString());
    
            Files.write(Paths.get(prop.getProperty("testClasspath")),doc_classpath.toString().getBytes());
```

my xml current

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/java">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/resources">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/test/lib_local/activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/test/lib_local/ahClient-1.0_A41.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/test/lib_local/ahClient-1.0_A51.jar"/>
               <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true" />
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true" />
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true" />
            <attribute name="test" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true" />
            <attribute name="test" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

when i execute the programme i see extra cml tags removed. Any help with this?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your input file is missing closing `</classpath>` tag it works for me! https://i.stack.imgur.com/93vSU.png Make sure the correct path is passed in `prop.getProperty("testClasspath")`.

Comment: when u say it works does it give u the classpath entry with kind=con @KrystianG

Comment: did u also write to file?..the path is correct otherwise the file doesnt get read in @KrystianG..i dont know what is wrong  here

Comment: @KrystianG i see that there are commented <!--<classpathentery>blasdasd</>--> in file is there a way to removes those?

Comment: When jsoup parses HTML/XML it ignores comments so when you parse it and save to file the comments won't be there.